# Should I sanitize and validate?

Tags: wordpress, validation, sanitization

For me it's not always clear when I need to validate and sanitize userinput. I think some might say "always", but...

At the moment I am creating a theme with a backend theme options in the admin area. What I want to do is create a textarea wish will contain html that is going be outputted in the footer of the theme.

I was thinking about only escaping the value with the help of esc_textarea().

So basicly there is no validation, only some measurement to make sure it doesnt destroy the textarea because of it's content (let's say a user put in `</textarea>`).

So can you answer my specific question, but tell me some more about when I should validate and sanitize. So I am not asking how to do it, but only describing what should be done. I know of all the different helper functions, but dont know when to use what:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation

Comment: I am one of the people that is going to say always.

Comment: +1 to always. Never underestimate the power of script kiddies with too much time on their hands. Nice question, though.

Comment: you could check out [wp_kses()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) for only allowing certain tags (no `<iframe>`, `<script>`, etc?)

Comment: "Always" applying every kind of sanitation that exists is destructive and very unwise. It's not good advice. There is *one* right sanitation  method for each way the data is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer:

**Always Sanitize to the appropriate context.** Validate if the business case requires it.

Longer Answer:

### **Validation**

Validation is to ensure data correctness and usefulness.

If you're asking the user for a phone number or bank account number, you validate to ensure that it's digits and dashes like 123-456-789. If you're asking for an email address, you validate to ensure @ and a dot, etc.

You should validate user input twice.

Client side validation is for user experience. You can inform a user if their input is invalid without making a roundtrip to the server. However, client side validation can be bypassed so you should validate server side too, to ensure data integrity.

### Sanitization

Sanitization is to ensure data safety and to prevent code injection.

You should always sanitize according to how you use the input data.

In the simple case of storing user input in a DB and later writing it to the screen, you need to sanitize the data twice.

When you write user input to the DB, you want to first make sure it doesn't contain SQL injection, so you sanitize it appropriately for SQL injection.

Later, when you want to pull the data from the DB and display it, you need to sanitize it for HTML and Javascript injection before printing it on the screen.

---

To answer your comment:

NEVER trust user input. Validate the data. Even admin's make mistakes. Sanitize the data. Keep your site safe from code injection.

The correct logic would be something like this:

Input:

Raw input -> Validate (client side) -> Send to server -> Validate again (server side) -> SQL Sanitize -> Store in DB.

Output:

Read data from DB -> Sanitize for HTML and JS -> Print to screen.

Comment: So what does that mean in my case where you need to be an admin to reach the page in question. Cause it is an admin should I just trust it? I seen a diagram somewhere wish goes as fallow: "Raw input" -> "Validation" -> (<--input side) -> "Storage (db)" -> (output side -->) -> "sanitization" --> "print". Is this logic right?

Comment: NEVER trust user input. Validate the data. Even admin's make mistakes. Sanitize the data. Keep your site safe from code injection.